# Point all subdomain lookups to WHM server for resolution from godaddy DNS

Tags: dns, cpanel, whm, godaddy-api

So I have a WHM server and each subdomain will have it's own cPanel account. That means it will have its own DNS zone on the server. When I set my local DNS server to the WHM server on the internet it resolves the hostnames fine. Although in godaddy dns I setup an A record pointing to the WHM servers IP address called "ns1" and that gets autofilled with my domain at the end. Then I setup an NS record for "*.free" (again my domain is at the end, but isn't needed in the record) to point to ns1.mydomain. Long story short it doesn't work. Is this even possible?? My DNS knowledge is alright, but I could use some help!

I tried adding the DNS reocrds in godaddy DNS

A: ns1 -> my WHM IP
NS: *.free -> ns1.mydomain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correction to this! I typed it in wrong.

if you add just create the record as follows:

NS subdomain -> mydomain.com.

It sends all subdomains for that subdomain to the Name Server you added. An example would be

test.subdomain.mydomain.com will be resolved at the mydomain.com. because it is a name server.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.

#### NS Record

NS *.subdomain -> mydomain.com.

is all that needed to happen. With the A record in GoDaddy as

#### A Record

A @ -> my ip address